# WSO2 Esb VFS through proxy

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am currently trying to set up a vfs proxy which works fine on a local ftp server. The problem is that our company internet access is blocked by a proxy so I am searching for how to specify this proxy information. As far as I know JSCH is used underneath but I haven't found a way to pass the proxy parameter.

Here is my current proxy xml:

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
name="ftpCollection" statistics="disable" trace="disable" transports="vfs">
<target>
    <inSequence>
        <clone>
            <target sequence="processSeq"/>
        </clone>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence/>
    <faultSequence/>
</target>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileURI">vfs:sftp://user:pw@192.168.2.99:22/reply</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.PollInterval">15</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">MOVE</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.FileProcessInterval">100</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">vfs:sftp://user:pw@192.168.2.99:22/process/</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess">vfs:sftp://user:pw@192.168.2.99:22/success/</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterFailure">vfs:sftp://user:pw@192.168.2.99:22/failure/</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">.*.xml</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.Locking">disable</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">application/xml</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterFailure">MOVE</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveTimestampFormat">yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS</parameter>
</proxy>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SFTP (SSH) through a proxy does work over a [HTTP tunnel](http://daniel.haxx.se/docs/sshproxy.html). [You can do that with JSch described on this page.](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/ViaHTTP.java.html)

Now already the VFS transport in WSO2 (which finally uses JSch) does not have an implementation of the HTTP tunneling. **So you cannot use a simple VFS WSO2 ProxyService to do that**.

You can solve it by **implementing your own wso2esb transport listener**. Have a look at the code of [VFSTransportListener.java](https://wso2.org/jira/secure/attachmentzip/unzip/52141/29708%5B4%5D/VFS2TransportListener.java) (or just copy/paste) and code the JSch access over http yourself. You can then add the transport in the axis2.xml configuration of your wso2esb.